# Why can't I set the value to a @State var without getting this error?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

So I have a State var called `calmnote` that is defined as a string in this struct called `calmEdit`. I essentially need to set the value of `calmNote` to the value of `content` received through an Observable Object called `calmManager`.

```
struct calmEdit : View {
@StateObject var CalmManager = calmManager()
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
@State var calmNote: String = ""

@ViewBuilder
var body: some View {
  
    EmptyView()
    
    ForEach(CalmManager.calmDoccs) { calmDoccs in
    
        self.calmNote = calmDoccs.content  as! String ?? "" // Error: Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'
    
          
      TextEditor(text: $calmNote)
  .padding(.top, 0)
      .padding(.leading, 10)
      .padding(.trailing, 10)
   

    Button( action: {
        CalmManager.updateCalmTheme(calmContent: calmNote, id: idcalm)
    }) {
        Label("Save", systemImage:"") }
    .accentColor(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.pink : Color.pink)
        .padding(10)
    
            }}
 }
```

Now if I remove the  `self.calmNote = calmDoccs.content  as! String ?? "` line i don't get any error, but then again, I won't be able to set the value of the var `calmNote` to `calmDoccs.content`. Does anyone know how I can achieve this by not getting this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You try to bind many rows to one state, that's wrong, instead separate row into standalone view, inject there `calmDoccs` from `ForEach` and there you could work with per-row model. But states are not assigned in body, do this either in `init` or `onAppear`, or any other action closure.

Comment: May be it's should be `@StateObject var calmManager = CalmManager()` and `ForEach(calmManager.calmDoccs)`?

Comment: @Asperi I'm not sure what exactly you mean by that. Pardon my ignorance because I'm still learning. So honestly I only really have one document being returned from calmManager and I don't really NEED to use ForEach. Do you know if there's a way to render the data returned from calmManager without using `ForEach(calmManager.calmDoccs)`? Like can I declare `calmManager.calmDoccs` in the view view without using `ForEach`?

Comment: You can’t set your state from within the view builder like that. Use the `.onAppear` or `.task` view modifier and add your line to set the State in there.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot perform operations like setting a variable from the `ViewBuilder` like that.

Use the `.onAppear` or `.task` modifier to run your code when the view appears.

```
EmptyView()
    .onAppear {
        self.calmNote = CalmManager.calmDoccs.content as? String ?? ""
    }
```

Additionally, with this line:

```
calmDoccs.content  as! String ?? ""
```

You are forcing it to be a String using ! but saying if it’s not a string use "" which obviously can’t happen.

Comment: So I tried this and I'm getting a weird error that 'Value of type '[calmDocc]' has no member 'content' even though my code does return a value of content like `calmDoccs = calmDocc(content:content, id:idcalm)`. I have another place in the code where I use `calmDoccs.content` but it doesn't seem to work here. Anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you miss an `s` off the end?